# TFS: How to delete a team project that failed during create?

Tags: tfs

When trying to create a project in TFS, the CreateProject activity fails.  However, the job exists and any attempts to create a project with the same name will fail due to duplicates.  Even though the system is treating these failed creations of projects as legitimite and existing items, they are not available for use.  If you view the web portal or source control explorer in TFS, the projects are not in the list.

[image: failedjobs]

[image]

Now that the root issue (the one that caused the activities to fail) is fixed, I want to delete these so I can recreate them.  Since the projects don't show up in the web client, I can't delete them, and the delete option in the management console isn't available for projects with a blank State.  Furthermore, every time I attempt to "Rerun Job", it just tells me that I can't.  There's no descriptor as to why I can't.

Is there a way I can manually remove these project entries from the source of data without damaging the rest of the system?  Or are there supported means for overcoming such an obstacle?

Comment: Have you resolved the issue by Hamid's solution? any update?

Comment: @Andy-MSFT Hamid gave good advice, in my case however, I was able to jump-start the service again and it automatically picked up those failed jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the TFSDeleteProject utility to destroy the project i.e. get rid of all the data remnants of deleted project.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/command-line/tfsdeleteproject-cmd

PS: Please use it with caution as you can do quite a bit of damage if you are not careful.